# why does $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ converge?

Tags: calculus

why does $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ converge?
I use the integral test for this series and I check the properties such as $a_n>0$ and decreasing but I can not complete the solving

Comment: It does not converge. Use the Integral Test. Note that $\ln(\ln x)$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x\ln x}$.

Comment: It doesn't converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^n\dfrac{1}{2^n\cdot \ln(2^n)}=\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n\ln 2}=+\infty\to \text{ the original series diverges !}$